# Processing the values of a grouping independently

Tags: powershell

How do you process the values of a group independently?

For example, I have the following grouping:

```
$grouping = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Group-Object Extension
```

I'd like to perform some operation on each set of the grouped child items:

```
foreach ($group in $grouping}
{ 
    $group.Values | Measure-Object
}
```

(`Measure-Object` is just a stand-in for an actual operation. I know getting the count can be done via `$grouping` directly.)

What I'm expecting is something like:

```
Count    : 96
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :

Count    : 12
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :

Count    : 14
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

What I get is:

```
Count    : 122
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

The `Measure-Object` cmdlet is being instantiated once for the *entire pipeline*, not once per set of values.

How do I instantiate it once per set of values?

**20150220 EDIT:**

I've posed the actual problem as a separate, but [much more specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638771/combining-group-object-and-foreach-object).

Comment: Think you are looking for `$group.Group | Measure-Object` possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same output that @BaconBits reported with your code. The way I was able to get you desired output was to use the following:

```
foreach ($group in $grouping)
{ 
    $group.Group | Measure-Object
}
```

But that only addresses your provided sample and potentially not your actual issue.

If that is still not working for you you need to be more explicit with you issue and sample if possible.

Comment: No, you didn't explicitly state it but you covered his issue. He needs to address the `.Group` member of each grouping. What I see people do fairly often is to pipe it into `Select -Expand Group` and then run their ForEach from that such as `ForEach($Group in ($grouping | select -expand group)){<do stuff for that group>}` or `$grouping | select -expand group | ForEach{ <do stuff for that group>}`

Comment: He answered the question I asked, but due to the way that I worded the question, it doesn't help the actual issue. I've reposted it, but gave Matt credit for his answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code, I get:

```
Count    : 1
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

But I get that once for every extension found.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but when I run this `$group.Values` is a `System.Collections.ArrayList` but only contains one value.

So `$grouping.Values` displays (for example):

```
.pdf
.txt
.txtfoo
.ps1
<etc.>
```

And `$grouping[0].Values`, which is what `$group.Values` would be for the first iteration, displays:

```
.pdf
```

And that's it.

My guess is you either want `foreach ($group in $Grouping.Values)` to iterate through each extension, or like @Matt says you should refer to `$group.Group` to get a the collection of items in that grouping.  I have no idea which since I have no idea what you're actually trying to do.