# Combining Group-Object and ForEach-Object?

Tags: powershell

I'm developing a cmdlet called `Merge-Xsd` that can merge similar XML schemas. It takes a list of paths, loads the schemas, merges them, and produces an `XMLDocument` as output.

All schemas of a particular file name are considered "similar", and so what I'm doing is getting all of the child items in a particular directory structure, grouping them according to the file name, and then trying to pass them to my custom cmdlet.

Grouping them is easy:

```
$grouping = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.xsd |
    Group-Object -Property Name -AsHashTable -AsString
```

However, processing them as part of the same pipeline is not. I've gotten as close as this:

```
$grouping.Keys |
    ForEach-Object { ($grouping[$_] |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Merge-Xsd).Save("C:\Out\$_") }
```

But what I'd *really* like to be able to do is use `ForEach-Object` directly after `Group-Object` to iterate over each group item, thus eliminating the need for the separate `$grouping` variable.

How can I use `ForEach-Object` to get the key/value pair while keeping each invocation of `Merge-Xsd` scoped to that particular key/value pair?

**20150224 UPDATE:**

The `Merge-Xsd` option set is extremely basic:

```
NAME
    Merge-Xsd

SYNTAX
    Merge-Xsd [-Path] <string[]>  [<CommonParameters>]
```

It is really just intended for throwing a bunch of files at it in one go and having them merged into a single output, which is an `XmlDocument`. (I modeled the output off of `ConvertTo-Xml`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could just nest it like this:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.xsd |
    Group-Object -Property Name | 
        ForEach-Object { 
           ($_.Group.FullName | Merge-Xsd).Save("C:\Out\$($_.Name)")
        }
```

I don't have your cmdlet or files but in my limited testing this would work.

### Some Explanation

I took out the `-AsHash` and `-AsString` parameters so we could deal directly with the group objects returned by `Group-Object`.

The `$_.Group.FullName` is more complex than it seems on first glance. `$_` here refers to a single group object, since we're in a `ForEach-Object`. The group object contains a property called `Name` which is the name of the group, and a property called `Group` which is actually a collection of the the individual items within the group, so `$_.Group` is a collection.

From here, it would make sense to pipe *that* to `ForEach-Object` again, since each of the items in that collection will be a FileInfo object, and you want to get the `FullName` property to pass to `Merge-Xsd`.

Here we take advantage of some powershell magic. When you refer to `$c.Property` where `$c` is a collection of objects with a `Property` property, you get back a collection that consists of the property objects.

So `$props = $c.Property` is the same as:

```powershell
$props = $c | ForEach-Object { $_.Property }
```

Knowing that, we can pipe `$_.Group.FullName` directly into `Merge-Xsd` to pass along *all of the fullnames from all of the files in the group*.

In that context, `$_.Name` still refers to the group object, so it's the name of the group, not the name of the file.

Comment: You need another bracket in front of `$_.Fullname` maybe? something is wrong there..... just not sure what

Comment: Yes @Matt, thanks. Actually after reviewing, it was completely in the wrong place for the new code. If I understand `Merge-Xsd` correctly (without seeing it), then the new way is how it would work. Maybe the poster can clarify.

Comment: Ok, actually, I had it way overcomplicated. I think it's much simpler now.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, and it works perfectly in testing. Thank you so much! Is that PowerShell magic regarding the auto-expanding collection property documented anywhere?

Comment: I found a description: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx

Comment: Nice, I had forgotten the name, thanks for the link.